# Cannot have file provisioner working with Terraform on DigitalOcean

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean, terraform

I try to use Terraform to create a DigitalOcean node on which consul is installed.

I'm using the following `.tf` file but it hangs up and do not copy the consul .zip file onto the droplet.

I got the following error message after a couple of minutes:

> ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods
>   [none publickey], no supported methods remain

The droplets are correctly created though. I can login on command line with the key I specified (thus not specifying password). I'm guessing the connection part might be faulty but not sure what I'm missing.

Any idea ?

```
variable "do_token" {}

# Configure the DigitalOcean Provider
provider "digitalocean" {
    token = "${var.do_token}"
}

# Create nodes
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "consul" {
    count = "1"
    image = "ubuntu-14-04-x64"
    name = "consul-${count.index+1}"
    region = "lon1"
    size = "1gb"
    ssh_keys = ["7b:51:d3:e3:ae:6e:c6:e2:61:2d:40:56:17:54:fc:e3"]

    connection {
        type = "ssh"
        user = "root"
        agent = true
    }

    provisioner "file" {
        source = "consul_0.7.1_linux_amd64.zip"
        destination = "/tmp/consul_0.7.1_linux_amd64.zip"
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
          "sudo unzip -d /usr/local/bin /tmp/consul_0.7.1_linux_amd64.zip"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not knowledable about DO, but `ssh_keys = ["7b:51:d3:e3:ae:6e:c6:e2:61:2d:40:56:17:54:fc:e3"]` does not look like ssh key.

Comment: in the resource, Terraform allow to put the fingerprints of the keys. This part is working fine though as I'm able to issue a ssh with this key to the droplet once it's created.

Comment: Have you tried passing the private key explicitly in the `connection` provisioner?

Comment: When I look at the [source](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/communicator/ssh/provisioner.go#L76) it looks like its also looking for the SSH env var `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to be set.  Is that set on your system appropriately?

Comment: @PaulTyng it seems that SSH_AUTH_SOCK is exported when issuing a ssh-agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform requires that you [specify the private SSH key](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html#private_key) to use for the connection with `private_key` You can create a new variable containing the path to your private key for use with Terraform's file interpolation function:

```
connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "root"
    agent = true
    private_key = "${file("${var.private_key_path}")}"
}
```

Comment: if agent set to true - it doesn't. with your answer i've got that `password protected keys are not supported. Please decrypt the key prior to use`

Answer (score 1):

You face this issue, because you have a ssh key protected by a password. To solve this issue you should generate a key without password.